# How do concatenated function calls in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

I just saw this code example from the crypto-library of node.js and wondered how this kind of "concatenated" function-calls are implemented?

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).update(salt).digest('base64');
```

Comment: It is called [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of one function is an object (probably the original object, `this` here). A property of that object is another function.

```js
var myObj = {
  foo: function() {
    alert("foo");
    return this;
  },
  bar: function() {
    alert("bar");
    return this;
  }
};

myObj.foo().bar().bar().foo().bar();
```

Comment: couldn't say it better my self, +1

Comment: Thank you! I will accept as far as I can. I would remove the last .foo() or add one .bar() so that it's possible to see, that the functions are called from left to right.